# I am unable to use iter_rows() to iterate excel and add cell values as a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, excel, dictionary, openpyxl

I am new to python but I have been trying to create a list of dictionaries that reads (openpyxl) from an Excel file. Using iter_rows() to read all the rows in the file and then add each row as a dictionary. The script then appends that dictionary to a list but when viewing the list of dictionaries it only shows the last row (or dictionary) is appended several times. I am not sure why its only appending the last row?

[Input Excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALwdh.gif)

```
import openpyxl
 
# Give the location of the file
path = 'C:\\Users\\.....\\pythonExcelDemo.xlsx'
 
# workbook object is created
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)

thisList = []
inner_dict = {}

sheet_obj = wb_obj.active

for row in sheet_obj.iter_rows(2, 6, 1, 3):
    for cell in row:
        if cell.column == 1:
            inner_dict.update({'Students Name': cell.value})
        if cell.column == 2:
            inner_dict.update({'Department': cell.value})
        if cell.column == 3:
            inner_dict.update({'Fund': cell.value})
    thisList.append(inner_dict)    
print(thisList)


Output-----

[{'Students Name': 'Keli', 'Department': 'Branch', 'Fund': 160}, {'Students Name': 'Keli', 'Department': 'Branch', 'Fund': 160}, {'Students Name': 'Keli', 'Department': 'Branch', 'Fund': 160}, {'Students Name': 'Keli', 'Department': 'Branch', 'Fund': 160}, {'Students Name': 'Keli', 'Department': 'Branch', 'Fund': 160}]
```

Comment: Hey @Keli, welcome to stackoverflow! I fixed your python formatting, in future make sure to indent or use ticks so it formats appropriately, see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Hey thankyou very much, I will certainly remember that, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're missing here is key point about Python.  You're not creating a set of dictionaries.  You're creating exactly ONE dictionary, modifying it during each loop, and creating a list with many references to that one dictionary.  When you change one, you change them all. You need to create a new dict every loop.  Do this:

```
for row in sheet_obj.iter_rows(2, 6, 1, 3):
    inner_dict = {}
    for cell in row:
        if cell.column == 1:
            inner_dict['Students Name'] = cell.value
        elif cell.column == 2:
            inner_dict['Department'] = cell.value
        elif cell.column == 3:
            inner_dict['Fund'] = cell.value
    thisList.append(inner_dict)    
print(thisList)
```

Comment: Oh WOW! thankyou very much Tim, you solved it. I should have come here 3 days ago. Yay!! It makes alot of sense